# Erro no AndroidManifest.xml 'class' or 'interface' excepted

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Fiz alguma besteira e o Manifest não reconhece o nome das Activitys

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

O `android:name=".Login"` fica com erro e aparece a mensagem: 'class' or 'interface' excepted

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Depois do susto consegui resolver, era só clicar na opção un-inject Language/Reference

Comment: Responda a sua pergunta e coloque os passos para a solução. Isso vai ajudar quem tiver o mesmo problema no futuro.

Comment: @ReneFreak obrigado pela dica! Editei a minha pergunta para colocar os prints. Agora acho q ajuda a quem tiver o mesmo problema.

Comment: Coloca na `Resposta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO

Esse foi o erro q cometi ao tentar adicionar uma nova Activity no Manifest 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de quebrar a cabeça procurando uma solução, eis que na base das tentativas consegui corrigir
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Era simples, mas passei algumas horas até conseguir